# Javascript Json problem in IE9

Tags: javascript, json, internet-explorer

Hy guys. In firefox and chrome this script alerts 'myclass', but does nothing in IE (i have version 9).

```
var a = {"class" : "myclass"};   
alert(a.class);
```

if I use cssclass instead of class, it is working in IE too.

```
var a = {"cssclass" : "myclass"};   
alert(a.cssclass);
```

This is very annoying. Is the word 'class' reserved in IE, or what can be the problem, and what is the solution?

Comment: have you tried with **a['class']**?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think `class` is a reserved keyword. Because objects are associative arrays in javascript you could also use this to access the value:

```
alert(a['class']);
```

Comment: @Tamas Pap, glad I could help. Is there something else you would like to ask?